# Moving head of an object in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I imported an object model from Blnder to openGL. The object contain a body and head. 
What is the simplest way for getting the head move right/left using OpenGL? I familiar with creating Armatures in Blender. Is there a way to import them too ?

Comment: you just need to know the format of the file and parse it

Comment: @ratchetfreak what file ?

Comment: are you familiar with a parser for that kind of job? for openGL

Comment: I'm sure the format is documented somewhere, it's just a google away :)

Comment: @ratchetfreak: Blender's files are notoriously difficult to parse. Not because the structure itself is terribly complicated, but because they're essentially Blender process memory dumps with structure; so to read a .blend file and make sense of it a program must effectively *be* Blender.

Comment: @datenwolf but there are better formats that it can export IIRC

Comment: @user3576822: OpenGL doesn't deal with files and OpenGL doesn't know what "Armatures" are. What you'll have to do is export the Blender Armature (Bones and Vertex influence) and reimplement the Mesh deformation and it is done in the Armature Mesh modifier of Blender.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: Yes, but AFAIK none of the default exporters shipping with Blender covers all the functionality of Armatures (COLLADA maybe, but that's a horrible to process format). However writing exporters for Blender is easy and everything that's not Bulk data can be easily serialized into JSON or similar.

Comment: @datenwolf: what do you suggesting? theres simplest way?

Comment: @user3576822: If you want quick, immediate results, my suggestion is *not to use OpenGL directly*. OpenGL is a rather low level drawing API and things like Armature Deformation require some substantial effort to do with just OpenGL. I suggest you use some open source game engine library (Ogre, Irrlicht or similar) as a starting point, then. – If you really want to do this in just OpenGL you'll have to learn Quaternions, SLERP interpolation, read up on matrix palette skinning, animation curves usually require an understanding of Bezier interpolation… It's not a simple thing to do.

Comment: @datenwolf: TNX! my goal is to detect moves of an head in a video, display an avatar,and rotate its head according to the moves. Is your advice about using  game engine library will be sufficient for that? TNX again!

Comment: @datenwolf: TNX! can you answer my last question?

Comment: @user3576822: There's no **easy** way to export or import Blender Armatures. Yes, you absolutely can export them, alright. The problem is, that Blender internally does a few, well, interesting things (mathematically) to make them work and it takes quite some thinking to understand why that is done (this is not something you'll find in the books either, you have to talk to the developers about it). You'd have to replicate that then in your program as well. I think your best bet would be looking at the Blender Phython API, the Armature Modifier source code and chat with the Blender devs in IRC.